# How I can force the element in white background to put over others?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this menu and I would to have the mobile version, like this:

[image: wanted menu like this]

In this moment I'm in current situation:

[image: image of my menu now]

Probably I can use the css property **overflow** but I have no idea how to use it.

This is my html code of menu:

```
    <div data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" class="mainmenu w-nav">
  <a href="#" class="brand w-nav-brand">
    <img alt="Vetrauto" src="images/Risorsa-5.svg" class="logo">
  </a>
  <div class="container w-container nav-container">
    <nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu w-nav-menu" id="primary_nav_wrap">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/index.php" class="nav-link w-nav-link w--current">Home</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/chisiamo.php">Chi siamo</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/servizi.php" class="nav-link w-nav-link">Servizi</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/servizi/servizi-mobile.html">Servizi mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/servizi/oscuramento-vetri.html">Oscuramento vetri</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/servizi/wrapping.html">Wrapping</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/vantaggi.php" class="nav-link w-nav-link">I vantaggi per voi</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/galleria.php" class="nav-link w-nav-link">Galleria</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/galleria/riparazione-mobile.php">Riparazione mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/galleria/oscuramento-vetri.php">Oscuramento vetri</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/galleria/wrapping.php">Wrapping</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/contatti.php" class="nav-link w-nav-link">Contatti</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-button w-nav-button">
      <div class="icon w-icon-nav-menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my css code:

```
/* Sub menu */
#primary_nav_wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li:hover {
  background: #ffed00;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block
}
```

I have no a demo and I cannot make it because are too many code to display. 
Link of problem: http://www.alpastomendrisio.ch/index.php 
The button for menu can view from a width of 990 px of screen.

Comment: Please provide a pen with a working demo of your problem.

Comment: I have too much code for create a pen, if you want I can give my web site link and there you can analyze the problem, it's okay for you? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the z-index of your sub menu unordered list element. To make it appear on top, apply the index property to `#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover>ul` element. Or statically to the sub menu dropdown lists

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

or statically (i.e. not on hover)

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul li>ul {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: If you look at the first image, which is the example, it appears as though the sub-menu items are visible while the first item is selected, like a toggleable collapsible menu. Z-index ordering won't work if you want the items to be inline with the rest of the menu. Also, since it is mobile, hover state is not an ideal approach for UX.

Comment: The question does not specifically ask to provide a mobile friendly menu, it asks to fix the issue of the layered lists which can be solved with z-index.

Comment: `"I have this menu and I would to have the mobile version, like this"` First part of the question.

Comment: He does not asks to provide the menu solution. He expresses his current situation and shows his implementation. I provide a fix for his current layering problem so he can move forward. The first pasted image is someone else's website.

Comment: I took the posted website example as "I'm trying to imitate this, help me"